# Variable considered NoneType at run time, but logging shows the correct values

Tags: python, flask

I have a flask route where i'm posting JSON data to. Requests are converted to python dictionaries through this function.

```
def request_handler(request_data):

    try:
        data = json.loads(request_data)
    except ValueError:
        return jsonres("error", "bad json")

    return data
```

The route i'm having trouble with looks like:

```
@mod_api.route('/thing/create', methods=['POST'])
@api_token_required
def create_thing():
    if request.method == 'POST':

        data = request_handler(request.data)
```

In all other routes I can grab values from keys and work with them using `data.get('key-name')` without troubles. Though on this particular route I get errors because the values of data are considered NoneType. Though if I log the value, type, or any other info about values from  the data variable it shows up as it should in the logging.

`logging.debug(type(data))` results in `<dict>`
`logging.debug(data.get('starttime')` results in `123123` (made up number but it shows the epoch integer i'm looking for properly)

```
starttime = data.get('starttime') + 1
```

results in

> Python Error: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'

Logging will show me everything correctly about the value of keys in data. As soon as I try to do anything with that value it considers it a NoneType resulting in server error.

This is happening with all of the data in various keys and types on this route.

Comment: uh.. what is the log output?

Comment: `get` returns `None` by default if the key does not exist. Are you sure it always exists? To discover this try using `data['starttime']` instead. If you see an exception, there is your issue. Is there a reasonable default value you can use in your `get` call?

Comment: Please add `print(data.get('starttime'))` and tell us the result. Thank you.

Comment: I'm sure the key exists. If I do `logging.debug(data)` it prints out all of the keys and their values.

Comment: @Qlstudio this is the result

```
[DEBUG] 2016-07-26 01:12:49.525GMT controllers - create_thing - 363: 1469492400000
```

same result if I use print. It shows the integer value

Comment: @PaulRooney using the brackets results in a keyerror. I'm confused why logging will spit out the correct value i'm looking for (using [ ] or get) but as soon as I try to manipulate the data it thinks it's a NoneType. Apparently logging and print can find the key.

Comment: It could simply be thats its not always there. You could catch the exception and act accordingly or if possible define a default value for the times when the `starttime` value is not present. Otherwise look at what is providing the data and ensure it always sets that value.

Comment: It's a user defined value that I can't set a default to. I'm pretty sure it's always there. I'm testing this locally and verifying it on the frontend and backend. The Nonetype occurs when trying to manipulate any of the values in the dict.

This is a very strange situation and I don't have any similar issues on any of the other routes. I think i'll just have to try and work around this somehow, or try testing with some working routes to see if the behavior is replicated with this request. Thanks for helping me step through this.

Comment: You could also check that there is not one path through your code that is accidentally invalidating the key.

Comment: stick `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` at the beginning of your function then go step by step, and I bet you will find what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`data = request.get_json( force=True, silent=True )`